# CloudWatch dashboard: Environment failed to launch as it entered Terminated state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I'm getting this error when something is wrong with a config file in the .ebextensions folder. There is nothing more in the log that would help. Where can I find additional information on what went wrong in cases like this?

Log excerpt:

```
08:09:42 UTC+0200   ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  pca-test    The following resource(s) failed to create: [pcaBackendEnvironment100WkHrs]. . Rollback requested by user.
08:09:42 UTC+0200   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment  pcaBackendEnvironment100WkHrs   Environment failed to launch as it entered Terminated state
Physical ID:pca-test
Client Request Token:Console-CreateStack-45f9fd76-b43a-48ec-bab1-34f27f02c239
08:09:11 UTC+0200   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::
Environment pcaBackendEnvironment100WkHrs   Resource creation Initiated
```

In this case, the error started after adding the Resources section to this file. Can anyone tell what's wrong with it?

*.ebextensions/cloudwatch.config:*

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs:
    StreamLogs: true

Resources:
  dashboard:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
    Properties:
      DashboardName: !Ref AWSEBEnvironmentName
      DashboardBody: !Sub |
        {
          "widgets": [
            {
              "type": "metric",
              "x": 6,
              "y": 0,
              "width": 6,
              "height": 6,
              "properties": {
                  "view": "timeSeries",
                  "stacked": false,
                  "metrics": [
                      [ "AWS/ApplicationELB", "RequestCount", "LoadBalancer", "${AWSEBV2LoadBalancer.Name}", { "stat": "Sum" } ]
                  ],
                  "region": "eu-west-1",
                  "period": 300
              }
            }
          ]
        }
```